# Replace string 1 only when string 2, 3, or 4 present

Tags: text-processing, replace

Basically I am an oracle dba. 
We have a task to switch-over from primary db to standby db and we need
tns entries (host-name) to be modified from `sape-scan` to `sapi-scan`
in the `tnsnames.ora` file containing tns connection entries `SAP_PROD`, `GOLD_PROD`, and `EVENTS_SAP`.

Example:

```
SAP_PROD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = sape-scan.walmart.net)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = SAP)
    )
  )
```

sape-scan should get changed to sapi-scan if the tns entry found as SAP_PROD

Comment: for people who aren't DBA's, is that format flexible? Will "SAP_PROD" always be 3 lines above any "sape-scan" text? Can "HOST" and "sape-scan..." be on separate lines?

Comment: My Apologies, I dont see a formatting tool here using which I can make it look as it should be.  Yes SAP_PROD will always be 3 lines above . It will work if we put it on seperate lines as long as the syntax is correct. But would be great if we keep it as it looks.

Comment: Look at the `{}` tool/button, it will format text as if you would find it in the config file.  My question was more around "could the tnsnames file have linebreaks in it that we would need to allow for, in the substitution"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jeff, There are no linebreaks in it.

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please use the checkmark to tell the system that the question is Answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming an entry starts when there is text in the first column, you can change those three entries with

```
awk '/^[A-Z]/ { substitute = ($1 ~ /^((SAP|GOLD)_PROD|EVENTS_SAP)$/) }
    substitute { sub(/sape-scan/, "sapi-scan") }1' tnsnames.ora >tnsnames.new
```

Awk processes each line from the input line according to the script, i.e. the text between the single quotes is a small program which is applied to each line in your file.

In this script, the variable `substitute` gets set to a boolean indicating whether the header line matches the regular expression. If the boolean is true, we perform the substitution on each line, until we see another header line, and the boolean's value gets evaluated again and possibly updated. The lone `1` causes every line to be printed.

The output is placed in a new file so you can `diff` etc against the original. If you are satisfied with the result, you can replace the old file simply by `mv`:ing the new file to the old file's name.

Comment: If I guessed wrong about the input file format, maybe [edit] your question to describe the file in more detail.

Comment: all - Thank you so much for all your inputs, really appreciate your efforts. It worked using the above command using awk. Thanks @triplee, Jeff , don_crissti , SuperKrish

Answer (score 2):

Another option, with sed:

```
sed -re '/^(SAP_PROD|GOLD_PROD|EVENTS_SAP) =/,/^$/s/HOST = sape-scan/HOST = sapi-scan/' tnsnames.ora
```

- turn on extended regular expressions (`-r`) for the `|` regex alternation
- take the next parameter (the quoted text) as an expression to evaluate (`-e`)
- between lines bracketed by either "SAP_PROD", "GOLD_PROD", or "EVENTS_SAP" at the beginning of the line, followed by space and equals sign, until a blank line,
- search and replace the text "HOST = sape-scan" with the text "HOST = sapi-scan"
- in the file tnsnames.ora

Use the above version to non-destructively test your changes, perhaps with:

```
sed ... tnsnames.ora > tnsnames.new
diff tnsnames.ora tnsnames.new
```

... to see what changed. In many sed implementations, you can add a `-i` flag to then make the changes "in-place".

Comment: Nope, It did not work. Using the above command its just displaying the whole file as it was earlier without any changes just like ' cat tnsnames.ora ' file command.

Comment: Perhaps there are no blank lines in the input file so the match criteria isn't fulfilled?

Answer (score -2):

Very simple brother, use `sed` like below

```
 sed -i -e 's/sape-scan/sapi-scan/g' $(grep -R 'SAP_PROD' ./ *ora|cut -d ':' -f1)
```

Thats it.:)

Comment: @don_crissti I update my answer, please check it

Comment: Thanks for your update Krish, I tried your answer but it did not work.       [oracle@testmachine1 admin]$ sed -i -e 's/sape-scan/sapi-scan/g' $(grep -R 'SAP_PROD' ./ *js|cut -d ':' -f1)
grep: *js: No such file or directory
[oracle@testmachine1 admin]$
[oracle@testmachine1 admin]$ ls -lrt tnsnames.ora
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall 189 Jul 13 20:20 tnsnames.ora
[oracle@testmachine1 admin]$

Comment: @don_crissti . That's absolutely correct . I have a file by name "tnsnames.ora" which contains hundreds of entries it should not modify "sape" to "sapi" in the entire file rather on match cases for "SAP_PROD,GOLD_PROD,EVENTS_SAP" . Thanks

Comment: @Mohammeddba , sorry i add please check now, I thought your file extension is  filename.ora. If yes try this, else change your file extension with *ora